# How to convert json object to QObject?

Tags: c++, json, qt, serialization, reflection

Json structure is C++ struct-like (struct or array of sturcts, arrays and basic types).
I need to convert JSON object to specified QObject with specified properties (by QObject fields).

For example, the json:

```
{
  "name": "Andrew",
  "age" 33,
  "identifiers": [32, 45, 67, 78],
  "more": {
     "gps": "44.9064', W073° 59.0735'",
     "valid": true
  }
}
```

QObjects:

```
class FMoreInfo : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT

   Q_PROPERTY( QString gps );
   Q_PROPERTY( bool valid );
}

class FPersonInfo : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT

   Q_PROPERTY( QString name );
   Q_PROPERTY( int32 age );
   Q_PROPERTY( QVector<int32> identifiers );
   Q_PROPERTY( FMoreInfo more );

}
```

JSON is a string and I need convert it by one template function to FPersonInfo.
Is there known algorithms?

Comment: Why not to use [QJsonObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) provided by Qt framework?

Comment: @mvidelgauz I have generated datatypes for manipulating. I don't know about QJsonObject, but I need directly handling to the object's fields:
`Obj->more->gps`

In other words QJsonObject is *implicit* object, I need the *explicit*.

Comment: So could you for example parse your json and add [Dynamic Properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dynamic-properties) to object? If you need thing like _generated_ member like `gps` than I don't think there is other way other than generating your QObject source code

Comment: @mvidelgauz in Unreal Engine 4 I can use `TFieldIterator` for iterating by structure\class properties and change them (by using type casting, if property can be casted to specified, then I can change them). Qt object has no any similar methods?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with Unreal Engine but to me it sounds like you can achieve your goal using Dynamic Properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been working on this problem myself, so far I've got a very rough implementation, it unfortunately does not support lists at all, there's no generic way to determine the type of the list and then add things to it, you could hard code support for specific list types you need if that will work for you.

```
QObject* Utils::fromJson(const QMetaObject& meta, QString& json)
{
    auto jsonObject = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json.toLatin1()).object();
    return fromJson(&meta, jsonObject);
}

QObject* Utils::fromJson(const QMetaObject* meta, QJsonObject& jsonObject)
{
    QObject* object = meta->newInstance();

    int propertyStart = QObject::staticMetaObject.propertyCount();
    for (int i = propertyStart; i < meta->propertyCount(); ++i) {
        QMetaProperty property = meta->property(i);
        if (!property.isWritable())
            continue;
        if (!jsonObject.contains(property.name()))
            continue;

        auto value = jsonValueToProperty(object, property, jsonObject.value(property.name()));
        property.write(object, value);
    }
    return object;
}

QVariant Utils::jsonValueToProperty(QObject* object, QMetaProperty& property, QJsonValue value)
{
    auto type = property.userType();
    auto typeName = QString(property.typeName());
    if (value.isArray()) {
        //todo array
    } else if (value.isObject()) {
        switch (type) {
        default:
            auto jsonObject = value.toObject();
            return QVariant::fromValue(fromJson(QMetaType::metaObjectForType(type), jsonObject));
            break;
        }
        //todo other meta object types
    } else {
        //primitive types
        return value.toVariant();
    }
}
```

Something to keep in mind is that each QObject type you want to convert must have a default constructor marked with `Q_INVOKABLE`, to use the it for your case might look something like this (assuming you put those methods into a class called `Utils`

```
QString json = QString(); //load json from somewhere
FPersonInfo*  person = (FPersonInfo*) Utils::fromJson(FPersonInfo::staticMetaObject, json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this as an open library: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqobjectserializer.

Define structures:

```
L_BEGIN_CLASS(FMoreInfo)
L_RW_PROP(QString, gps, setGps)
L_RW_PROP(bool, valid, setValid)
L_END_CLASS

L_BEGIN_CLASS(FPersonInfo)
L_RW_PROP(QString, name, setName)
L_RW_PROP(int, age, setAge)
L_RW_PROP(QList<int>, identifiers, setIdentifiers)
L_RW_PROP(FMoreInfo*, more, setMore)
L_END_CLASS
```

Done:

```
LDeserializer<FPersonInfo> deserializer(factory);
QScopedPointer<FPersonInfo> g(deserializer.deserialize(jsonString));
```

You also need to register the types in the meta object system as usual.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using extra code in property definition? 
If reflection info exists for each qproperty, why I can't just enumerate these properties in loop? Although it seems impossible to determine inner container type (such as QMap, QList) during runtime in qt framework... Or am I wrong?

Comment: I mean L_RW_PROP macro. Just code style: want to see the classic QObject class definition with Q_PROPERTY without additional Q_INVOKABLE functions (like in example in question)

Comment: You want to change the name? Redefine it. I do not see any Q_INVOKABLE function in my example.